# How to parse <div class ="abc"><h4 class="cvb">india</h4></div> in android

Tags: android

Hi friends I develop a app for parsing  web page in android.

```
<div class="list-group"><h4 class="list-group-item ui-header"NZ vs RSA, Christchurch</h4></div>.
```

I want parse `NZ vs RSA Christchurch` ,please help me.

Comment: Please try JSOUP to parse HTML tags..

Comment: please share me a sample.

Comment: Please google it based on the JSOUP..you will find more examples..

Comment: You're asking basically the same in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452287/how-to-parse-web-page-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
String extractedString = android.text.Html.fromHtml(htmlString).toString();
```

`fromHtml(String source)` method returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Jsoup` libray [here](http://jsoup.org/).Its the best way you can choose.

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

OR you can use default android `Html.fromHtml()`.

```
 String normalString = android.text.Html.fromHtml(stringforparse).toString()
```

Comment: Thanks friends.my question is that <div class="list-group"><h4 class="list-group-item ui-header"NZ vs RSA, Christchurch</h4></div>. i want parse NZ vs RSA, Christchurch.please guide me

Comment: Go to the link i provided above, the download the library, add the library to your project, use the first code placed here, pass the string you have to the function and it will return the value you need.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity{
 TextView text;
 String ss;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
  ss=html2text("http://m.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match/live-scores");
  text.setText(""+ss);
  
 }
 public static String html2text(String html) {
     return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
 }
}

and answer is http://m.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match/live-scores

Comment: you are passing the url "m.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match/live-scores", instead you have to pass the data <div class="list-group"><h4 class="list-group-item ui-header"NZ vs RSA, Christchurch</h4></div> ,  ss=html2text("<div class="list-group"><h4 class="list-group-item ui-header"NZ vs RSA, Christchurch</h4></div>");