# How to parse web page in android

Tags: android

i have a web url http://m.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match/live-scores which page source is
`<div class="list-group"><h4 class="list-group-item ui-header">ENG vs PAK, Sydney</h4></div>`

I want ENG vs PAK, Sydney,please hepl me

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448306/how-to-parse-div-class-abch4-class-cvbindia-h4-div-in-android

Answer (score 3):

> JSoup is one such open source library that provides an API for
>   extracting and manipulating data. Basically, it is an HTML parser used
>   for working with various HTML elements, attributes etc. It can also
>   find and extract data, using DOM traversal or CSS selectors.

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example""

String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
    // "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```

Visit [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/) it will help you with your problem, with that have a look on [cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)

Comment: Thanks Friends for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can user use JSOUP. It is an open source library used to parse HTML page.
You can give a look here http://jsoup.org/.

If you want to use it in Android you can give a look at my post in my blog where i explain how to use it:

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html

Hope this helps you!